# Double GET request in text file?

Tags: php, get

I have a file "host.php" which gives **plain text**. When I try to run it in browser, once per few refreshes one variable increases by 2, not 1. I tried placing session variable on end, to check if its script error (double var increment) or a http error. Looks like it increases the same way. Also checked Chrome Network debugger. Found one error (with browser trying to load favicon.ico), fixed it and the problem still occurs.

I have seen this question:
[What can cause a double page request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791119/what-can-cause-a-double-page-request) which had the same problem, but it wasn't solution for me. I don't use ads or html elements - its plain text.

The result:

> The page sometimes loads twice. There is no network errors, like empty src. And its plain text, not html.

The question:

> How to fix it? How to prevent page loading twice?

PS: The page never uses POST requests, only get.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it wasn't solution for me"? The answers to that question point out a few potential issues you might very well observe. What makes you so certain you run into _another_ issue?

Comment: @arkascha, It points that it might be result of using ads and invalid html srcs, while I don't use them. I would comment on this question, but I have no enough of rep...

Comment: Actually there are more potential reasons pointed out in the answers...

Comment: @arkasha, like? I readed all, or just most of them...

Comment: If you _really_ re-read all answers, then you certainly spotted things like "empty image reference", "double clicks", "browser inconsistency", "iframes"... Sorry, don't just insist there are no other options given when there clearly are.

Comment: @arhkascha, I do everything very carefully. No double click. And there is no iframes, I said its plain text, not html. And that I didn't pointed all those answer does not means that I didn't readed or thinked about 'em.

Comment: Then I suggest you take a network sniffer and start digging.

Comment: @Arkascha, Can YOU read carefully my question? I already checked Network Debugger

Comment: You would need to show us some code for us to even remotely help debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is it the correct answer, so I won;t yet mark it as correct.

When I tried the script in Chrome on other device (in Incognito mode), everything worked well (or I just didn't saw...). On my device I'm also using Chrome.

As Incognito mode uses different cookies probably even for each tab (?), it might be fault of some external cookies running (like in linked question, ads could import some). Chrome debugger now only shows 1 cookie, which is PHPSESSID from my site, it looks like its not that.

Afterall, I pressume that its user's device/browser/extensions fault. I also tried disabling Adblock, but that didn't solve the problem.