# Ajax requests keep doubling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website where on the main page there is a content div and content is being switched using ajax. Everytime I switch between different pages it seems to me like ajax keeps making double the amount of requests. Here is the code handling the page switching:

```
$(document).on('click','#sideNav a',function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); //get the link you want to load data from

    $.ajax({ 
     type: 'GET',
     url: url,
     success: function(data) { 
        $("#content").empty();
        $("#content").html(data); 
    } 
   }); 
   //window.history.pushState('object', 'New Title', url);
 });
});
```

Now lets say I switch to my templates page where it displays created templates and lets me create templates.

Now the first time I switch to this page and create a new template everyhting is fine, one post is made to php and one new entry is made to the database. Now if I switch between pages and back to my templates page and create a new template, only this time ajax makes two posts to php and 2 database entries are made, now if I do that one more time 4 posts are mad and so on.

It happens with every function that uses ajax. It doesn't happen when I go to my templates page seperately not through my main page with the content div, so I suspect something is messed up with how I switch pages.

Edit: it actually isn't doubling but adding one request each time.

**UPDATE** 
Somehow I fixed it, not exactly sure how but here's the things I did: I added `.off('click','#sideNav a')` to my function and I also put the function into separate .js file. I feel like it was loading the script again every time, again not exactly sure what exactly fixed it, hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Sounds like you keep loading the same script multiple times. I don't think you have shown enough to sort out the issue,

Comment: @charlietfl I was thinking the same thing but can't seem to find anything suggesting that I keep loading the same script, and I'm sorry I just don't know what else to post to make it any clearer.

Comment: Does the same script exist in the content templates?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm pretty sure that was the problem, although I removed the script once and tried and the problem persisted but maybe it was just me being stupid and not clearing the cache or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a solution to this you could use `off()` to dettach the click event (if exist) before attaching :

```
$(document).off('click','#sideNav a').on('click','#sideNav a',function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); //get the link you want to load data from
    $.ajax({ 
     type: 'GET',
     url: url,
     success: function(data) { 
        $("#content").empty();
        $("#content").html(data); 
    } 
   }); 
   //window.history.pushState('object', 'New Title', url);
 });
});
```

IMO the cause of this problem comes from the posted code when you call it multiple time every time you call it the event will be attached another time and so on.

Comment: Try to clear the cache using Ctrl+F5 , It should work, make sure you've not the same script rendered several times to your page...

Answer (score 0):

Your above script works just fine. Check out this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/N8tlyMljX0pmGKghRtwa?p=preview):

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.2.1" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Ajax request</h1>
    <div id="sideNav">
      <a href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      Some Content Goes Here
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#sideNav a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href'); //get the link you want to load data from

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      $("#content").empty();
      html = `<p><b>Name:</b> ${data.name}</p>
        <p><b>Email:</b> ${data.email}</p>
        <p><b>body:</b> ${data.body}</p>`
      $("#content").html(html);
    }
  });
  // window.history.pushState('object', 'New Title', url);
});
```

Checkout this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791119/what-can-cause-a-double-page-request) for other reasons that may cause your requests to be doubled.