# Multiple duplicate HTTP requests/queries from single requests in Azure with Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, postgresql

I have a Laravel app being served on Azure. I am using an AJAX request to poll data for a javascript chart.

The AJAX requests a URL defined in my routes (web.php), thus:

```
Route::get('/rfp_chart_data', 'DataController@chart_data')->name('chart_data');
```

That controller method runs a postgresql query and returns a JSON file. This all works fine.

However, after experiencing some performance issues, I decided to monitor the postgres queries and discovered that the same query was running 3 times for each request to this URL.

This happens regardless of whether I:

- access the URL via an AJAX request
- go directly to the URL in a     browser
- access the URL via cURL

This (AFAIK) eliminates the possibility that this is some sort of missing img src issue (e.g. [What can cause a double page request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791119/what-can-cause-a-double-page-request))

Thanks very much for any help...

**EDIT:**

Image of the duplicate queries in postgres pg_stat_activity -- this is from 1 web request:

[image: image of duplicate requests]

**EDIT:**

Full controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\AllRfpEntry;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables;

class DataController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Displays datatables front end view
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */

    //|| result_url || '\">' || result_title || '</a>'

    public function chart_data(Request $request) {

        $binding_array = array();

        $chart_data_sql = "SELECT relevant_dates.date::date,
            CASE WHEN award_totals.sum IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE award_totals.sum
            END
            as sum

            ,


            CASE WHEN award_totals.transaction_count IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE award_totals.transaction_count
            END
            as transaction_count FROM

            (
            SELECT * FROM generate_series('" . date('Y-m-01', strtotime('-15 month')) . "'::date, '" . date('Y-m-01') . "'::date, '1 month') AS date
            )  relevant_dates

            LEFT JOIN

            (
            SELECT extract(year from awarded_date)::text || '-' || RIGHT('0' || extract(month from awarded_date)::text, 2) || '-01'  as date, sum(award_amount)::numeric as sum, COUNT(award_amount) as transaction_count FROM all_rfp_entries

            WHERE awarded_date >= '" . date('Y-m-01', strtotime('-15 month')) . "'

            AND awarded_date <= '" . date("Y-m-d") . "' AND award_status = 'AWARDED'
            AND award_amount::numeric < 10000000000";

        if ($request->get('rfp_company_filter')) {

            $binding_array['rfp_company_filter'] = $request->get('rfp_company_filter');

            $chart_data_sql .= " AND company = :rfp_company_filter";

        };

        if ($request->get('rfp_source_filter')) {

            $binding_array['rfp_source_filter'] = $request->get('rfp_source_filter');

            $chart_data_sql .= " AND rfp_source = :rfp_source_filter";

        }

        if ($request->get('exclude_fed_rev')) {

            $chart_data_sql .= " AND rfp_source != 'US FED REV' ";

        }

        if ($request->get('rfp_year_filter')) {

            $binding_array['rfp_year_filter'] = $request->get('rfp_year_filter');

            $chart_data_sql .= " AND year = :rfp_year_filter";

        }

        if ($request->get('rfp_priority_level_filter')) {

            $binding_array['rfp_priority_level_filter'] = $request->get('rfp_priority_level_filter');

            $chart_data_sql .= " AND priority_level = :rfp_priority_level_filter";

        }

        if ($request->get('rfp_search_input_chart')) {

            $binding_array['rfp_search_input_chart'] = $request->get('rfp_search_input_chart');

            $chart_data_sql .= " AND search_document::tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', :rfp_search_input_chart)";

        }

        $chart_data_sql .= " GROUP BY extract(year from awarded_date), extract(month from awarded_date)
        ) award_totals
        on award_totals.date::date = relevant_dates.date::date

        ORDER BY extract(year from relevant_dates.date::date), extract(month from relevant_dates.date::date)
        ";

        return json_encode(DB::select($chart_data_sql, $binding_array));


    }

    public function data(Request $request) {

        $query = AllRfpEntry::select('id', 'year', 'company', 'result_title', 'award_amount', 'edit_column', 'doc_type', 'rfp_source', 'posted_date', 'awarded_date', 'award_status', 'priority_level', 'word_score', 'summary', 'contract_age', 'search_document', 'link');

        if ($request->get('exclude_na')) {

            $query->where('all_rfp_entries.company', '!=', 'NA');

        }

        if ($request->get('clicked_date')) {

            $query->where('all_rfp_entries.awarded_date', '>', $request->get('clicked_date'));

            $query->where('all_rfp_entries.awarded_date', '<=', $request->get('clicked_date_plus_one_month'));

        }

        if ($request->get('filter_input')) {

            $query->whereRaw("search_document::tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', '" . $request->get('filter_input') . "')");

        }

        $datatables_json = datatables()->of($query)

            ->rawColumns(['result_title', 'edit_column', 'link'])

            ->orderColumn('award_amount', 'award_amount $1 NULLS LAST')
            ->orderColumn('priority_level', 'priority_level $1 NULLS LAST');

        if (!$request->get('filter_input')) {

            $datatables_json = $datatables_json->orderByNullsLast();

        }

        if (!$request->get('filter_input') and !$request->get('clicked_date')) {

            $count_table = 'all_rfp_entries';

            $count = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT n_live_tup FROM pg_stat_all_tables WHERE relname = :count_table "), array('count_table' => $count_table))[0]->n_live_tup;

            $datatables_json = $datatables_json->setTotalRecords($count);

        }

            $datatables_json = $datatables_json->make(true);

        return $datatables_json;

    }


}
```

**EDIT:**

An even crazier wrinkle...

I have a method in Laravel on this server pointed at a postgres database on another server to ingest new data. I just found out that even THAT method (the one pointing at the external server) is generating multiple queries on the external postsgres server!

[image]

Unless I'm missing something, this obviates an nginx issue or an issue with my provider (Azure), or a problem with any one specific method. Even a straight database connection over port 5432 (I'm assuming that's how Laravel accesses external databases) is generating the multiplier effect, so it must be something screwy with my Laravel installation... but no closer to figuring out what.

Comment: How are you monitoring your query? Are you looking into the server logs or doing this through some debugger in the app?

Comment: I'm watching them real-time with: SELECT pg_stat_activity.pid,
    now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start AS duration,
    pg_stat_activity.query,
    pg_stat_activity.state
   FROM pg_stat_activity;;

Comment: I was wrong -- this issue is occurring on my local vagrant system as well. The queries were just happening too fast there to see them real-time. So this does not appear to be an Azure issue.

Comment: @BenWilson post your controller code so that we can identify why the queries are repeating.

Comment: Hi Paras -- I've edited my post with the full controller code

Comment: I think this has something to do with `datatables()` method call. If you look at the query that you've posted, its a aggregate count which is most likely used in pagination (It needs to know how many of something before it can say how many pages, right?)  Without knowing what that method is/does, I can't be more specific. But I believe your issue lies within that implementation.

Comment: Thanks Aaron -- but unfortunately the multiple queries also happen with the rfp_chart_data method, which doesn't use the datatables() method...

Comment: Your route is pointing to `DataController@chart_data` but the controller doesn't have that method

Comment: Are all the queries the same in the logs or do they seem to be missing parts based on the request uri/parameters provided?

Comment: Diogo -- sorry that was a typo. Renamed the function "rfp_chart_data" to chart_data. Also, see above for an additional interesting wrinkle... seems this is happening even when invoking a totally different method that's point to another server over port 5432! (postgres)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to debug this is to start a debug session with xdebug and stepping through the code while you keep an eye on the stdout/logging output in a separate window.

Set a breakpoint on the first line in your controller, when it breaks there should be 0 queries done. If not you know something weird is going on in routing/the request. Then step through the function calls used in building the query.

It might be that one of the functions you use triggers executing the query (as suggested by Aaron Saray) or methods are missing (as suggested by Diogo Gomes) but this is hard to tell without knowing the code or stepping through an execution context step-by-step.

If you do not have a debugger you can always use `dd($data);` at any line to stop processing too and dump the data given. It will just take a little longer because you'll be doing a new request for each step in the code.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I tracked this down to multiple postgres worker processes (which you can set in your postgres .conf file). So, not a bug, nor an issue with Laravel -- just parallel workers spawned by postgres.